# Forward message to another dialog from custom prompt

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm using [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/CSharp/demo-ContosoFlowers/ContosoFlowers.BotAssets/Dialogs/CancelablePromptChoice.cs) custom class to make custom prompt.

I modified tryParse method. I would like to forward message to the first Dialog if user does not choose any option.

Code :

```
   var promptOptions = new CancelablePromptOptions<string>(MyDictionary.ChooseOneOfTheFollowingOptions, cancelPrompt: "cancel", options: MyHelper.GetOptios(), promptStyler: PromptStyler);
            CancelablePromptChoice<string>.Choice(context, OptionSelected, promptOptions);
```

I'm trying to override TryParse function in CancelablePromptOptions class :

```
   protected override bool TryParse(IMessageActivity message, out T result)
        {
            if (IsCancel(message.Text))
            {
                result = default(T);
                return true;
            }

            bool b =  base.TryParse(message, out result);
            if (!b)
                Conversation.SendAsync(message, () => new MyFirstDialog());
                return base.TryParse(message, out result);
        }
```

Notice MyFirstDialog from code. I would like to recreate first dialog with the current message.

Goal : If user choose some Dialog where more options are stored and if the first "choose" is not valid, i would like to recreate MyFirstDialog.

Any idea ?

Edit :

MyFirstDialog is the first IDialog i'm calling from Messages controller.

```
await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new MyFirstDialog());
```

I'm calling current IDialog from MyFirstDialog :

`context.Call(new CurrentDialog(), CurrentDialog.HandleOptions);`

Comment: What would be the order in the dialogs? Should the user go back to this dialog after MyFirstDialog?

Comment: Yes. That's the first IDilog i'm calling from Messages controller. 

 `await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new MyFirstDialog());`

Comment: My question was more: what is the link between the current dialog in your code and MyFirstDialog that will be called after: do you need to go back to this dialog when MyFirstDialog is terminating?

Comment: I'm calling current IDialog from MyFirstDialog : 

`context.Call(new CurrentDialog(), CurrentDialog.HandleOptions);`

I want to recreate myFirstDialog if user  does not choose a valid option.

Comment: Can't you simply use the `ResumeAfter` in `context.Call(new CurrentDialog(), ...` and check the value passed in this method to see in which case you are?

Comment: Yes. But i don't know how to recreate MyFirstDialog. Any idea ?

Comment: When doing your context.Call from MyFirstDialog to CurrentDialog and you use ResumeAfter<type>, your MyFirstDialog will get the result, there is no need to "recreate" anything: MyFirstDialog is still in the dialog stack!

Comment: Can you provide an example to accept your answer. Btw, i will try your logic now.

Comment: Btw : My current IDialog is created this way :  `[Serializable]
    public class CurrentDialog: IDialog<string>`

Comment: I added a complete answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145868/discussion-between-nicolas-r-and-bob-swager).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example on how to go back to your initial dialog, starting for the lowest level.

**CancelablePromptChoice** code:

Here you let the basic implementation do the "TryParse", but if it's not matching you will handle it (by returning true and keeping the value), avoiding the retry

```
protected override bool TryParse(IMessageActivity message, out T result)
{
    if (IsCancel(message.Text))
    {
        result = default(T);
        return true;
    }

    var parsingTriedSucceeded = base.TryParse(message, out result);

    // here you know if you found one of the options or not, and if not you override
    if (!parsingTriedSucceeded)
    {
        result = (T)Convert.ChangeType(message.Text, typeof(T));
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return parsingTriedSucceeded;
    }
}
```

**CurrentDialog** code:

In this code you will handle your default(T) reply in the OptionSelected (which is the method called when this dialog is resuming after your prompt). By doing a `context.Done<string>(null);` you will end this dialog and go back to `MyFirstDialog`

```
[Serializable]
public class CurrentDialog : IDialog<string>
{
    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        var promptOptions = new CancelablePromptOptions<string>(MyDictionary.ChooseOneOfTheFollowingOptions, cancelPrompt: "cancel", options: MyHelper.GetOptions(), promptStyler: PromptStyler);
        CancelablePromptChoice<string>.Choice(context, OptionSelected, promptOptions);
    }

    private async Task OptionSelected(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
    {
        var chose = await result;
        string answer = chose.ToString();

        switch (answer)
        {
            case HelpEnumerator.Agenda:
                await EventHelper.GetEventAgenda(context);
                context.Done<string>(null);
                break;
            case HelpEnumerator.Register:
                context.Call(new RegistrationDialog(), RegistrationDialog.Resume);
                context.Done<string>(null);
                break;
            case HelpEnumerator.Speakers:
                await EventHelper.GetSpeakers(context);
                context.Done<string>(null);
                break;
            case HelpEnumerator.Tickets:
                await EventHelper.GetTickets(context);
                context.Done<string>(null);
                break;
            default:
                context.Done(answer);
                break;  
        }
    }
}
```

**MyFirstDialog** code:

So finally in your MyFirstDialog you have to handle this return from the CurrentDialog, using the resume method:

```
// Somewhere in your logic...
context.Call(new CurrentDialog(), ResumeAfterCurrentDialog);

// On your class:
private async Task ResumeAfterCurrentDialog(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
{
    // You are entering here after "context.Done(...)" in the CurrentDialog. To know the "result" value, take a look at what in the OptionSelected in CurrentDialog => it can be null for the options of the list, or the value in "answer" if it's not one of the options
    // So we only have to test if it's not null, and then send the message again to the bot by using the "context.Activity" value

    var resultText = await result;

    if (resultText != null)
    {
        // Send the message again. It's already the message stored in context.Activity ;)
        IMessageActivity msg = (IMessageActivity)context.Activity;
        await this.MessageReceivedAsync(context, new AwaitableFromItem<IMessageActivity>(msg));
    }
}
```

Comment: How to call this function :  `private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument)
        {`

This method is stored into MyFirstDialog. To resume whole Conversation. Maybe user clicked some other option from persistent menu ?

Comment: Where do you want to call it? From my `// Do you special treatment here when nothing was selected` section?
If you want to get what the user said in the prompt back to your MyFirstDialog you have to pass it in the Context.Done and change a bit of code

Comment: This `protected override bool TryParse(IMessageActivity message, out T result)` method should call MyFirstDialog. There is a logic for resuming IDialog or not. 
If it is false, it recreates promptChoice. Can't call MyFirstDialog from this function ... also from MakePrompt that function returns IMessageActivity. 

I want to use already existing msg to recreate MyFirstDialog. 

Any idea ?

Comment: I think you are not getting the dialog stack management. You must not create a new MyFirstDialog! Just call again MessageReceivedAsync of MyFirstDialog in the last ResumeAfter

Comment: answer modified after chat discussion